# Should I use "give" or "gives" in this statement:

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Should I use "give" or "gives" in this statement:

> Our team of Ag professionals, with countless years of  experience, give you the kind of home field advantage that goes unmatched.

Answer (score 3):

Particularly in British English, collectives like *team* often take a plural verb - *give* - especially where the *team* is qualified with "of professionals", inviting the hearer to treat the team as made up of its members.

So, in British usage, either is possible.

I believe American usage strongly prefers a singular, *gives*.

Answer (score -1):

Just shorten your sentence:

> Our team <s>of Ag professionals, with countless years of experience,</s> give you the kind of home field advantage that goes unmatched.

> Our team **gives** you the kind of home field advantage that goes unmatched

Comment: Sometimes "team" can be a collective noun and can be treated as plural.